# error when uploading to apigee

Tags: file-upload, apigee

Why do I get this error when I'm uploading to apigee?

> Both the operands for AND expression should be logical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your condition has a single boolean term, then a relational operator operators (e.g. '==') is not needed.

For example:

```
<Condition>(myBoolean)</Condition>
```

However if you have two or more terms that comprise your condition, you then need to use a relational operator for each term, as in:

```
<Condition>(myBoolean == true) and (mySecondBoolean == true)</Condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything more specific, like which operands?

I'd look in Conditions to see if you're trying to evaluate anything that is odd

Is it possible to do an assignment in a comparison?